# Example of GDAL GetAxisOrientation

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I did not find much documentation about GDAL `GetAxisOrientation`.

I saw an example :

```py
from osgeo import osr, gdal

myproj = osr.SpatialReference()
myproj.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
xaxis = myproj.GetAxisOrientation(None,0)
xaxis = myproj.GetAxisOrientation(None,1)
```

and the axis orientation for `SR=4326` output is `1 3`.

Can someone give me an example of the correct use of the `GetAxisOrientation` and correct meaning?

Comment: is the 4th line in your example meant to be `yaxis`

Answer (score 1):

The index returned by the `SpatialReference.GetAxisOrientation()` method refers to the **OGRAxisOrientation** enumeration in the native GDAL library.

You can find the meaning of such (0-based) index both in the return value section of the [method's javadocs](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/osr/SpatialReference.html#GetAxisOrientation(java.lang.String,int)):

> [...]
>
> **Returns**:
>
> axis orientation (org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_Other,
> org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_North, org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_South,
> org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_East, org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_West,
> org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_Up, org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_Down), or
> org.gdal.osr.osr.OAO_Other on failure.
>
> **Since:**
>
> GDAL 2.1

... and in the GDAL source code ([ogr_srs_api.h](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.5.2/ogr/ogr_srs_api.h#L48-L56) file):

```c
typedef enum {
    OAO_Other=0, /**< Other */
    OAO_North=1, /**< North */
    OAO_South=2, /**< South */
    OAO_East=3,  /**< East */
    OAO_West=4,  /**< West */
    OAO_Up=5,    /**< Up (to space) */
    OAO_Down=6   /**< Down (to Earth center) */
} OGRAxisOrientation;
```